# Firebird or PostgreSQL for POS application - What do you recommend (any advice, experience)?

Tags: database, c#, sql, postgresql, delphi

I am about to start POS application development and I can not decide between Firebird and PostgreSQL.

(Firebird 3 or PostgreSQL 12)

As for functionality both DBMS have everything I need.

When it comes to Firebird I am bit concerned about reliability, on the other hand PostgreSQL installation is about 20 time larger (9MB vs 192MB).

So if anyone can share some thoughts, advice or experience it would be very much appreciated !

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)